# Appium+android+selenium switch

Tags: android-activity, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I have login scenario in which when the user click on the signin button then the next activity is opened in which there is a list. i am new to appium and find it hard how to get the validation that the login is successfull.
I didnt got success with the below

driver.switchTo().window((String)driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[windowIndex]);

please guide how to get the current activity & move to awaiting activity, so that i can validate the object existance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just share the screenshot of the next activity and while launching your apk file with the starting activity name , there is no further need to specify the next activity names. Appium will run the next concurrent activitiesby itself.